# C++ - how does the || operator work?

Tags: c++, boolean, return

I have seen this syntax in a program but I am not sure what happens at the return part. What does the ||(or) mean? Does this mean that the method returns `true` when at least one of `a` and `b` is `true` and returns `false` when both of them are `false`?

```
    bool A::truthValue() {
    bool a = true;
    bool b = true;
    if(........)
       a= false;
    if(........)
       b=false

    return (a || b);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will return true if either b or a is true. This means that the result is (see table):

```
a | b | result
t | t | t
f | t | t
t | f | t
f | f | f
```

Actually in your specific case, false will be returned only if both `if` statements become true.

**EDIT** So - your suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It means return true if *a* **or** *b* is true.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that the method returns true when at leas one of a and b is true and returns false when both of them are false?

It means exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely: The || operator will first evaluade the expression on the left side. If it is true, the expression on the right side **is ignored** and the whole || expression evaluades to true. If the left expression is false, the right expression is evaluated; if it is true the whole || expression evaluades true, otherwise false.

This behavior is well defined and not trivial. This logic exlusion applies to all logic operators in C++, which allows things like:

```
if (p && *p != '\0')
```

Which would not be allowed, if this rule would not exist.